# Revert to default option on form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, html-select

I need to revert back to the default option on a form on a search results page on magento.

I have used the following Jquery and it works fine on firefox. The problem is with IE.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#form-validate-small option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
});
</script>
```

hope that makes sense

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#form-validate-small option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
    jQuery('#form-validate-small option:first-child').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
</script>
```

Got it working on http://jsfiddle.net/VDw7B/3/

Answer (score 0):

try jQuery('#form-validate-small option:selected').attr('selected', false);



**EDIT**

I've tried it on IE7 and found out it doesn't work.
should use proper property.
 
try,

```
jQuery('#form-validate-small option:selected').attr('checked', false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it results in the same problem, works fine in firefox, but not in ie.

Comment: @JamesDickinson I've checked it and edited my answer. tested on ie7.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to use the option that has

```
selected='selected'
```

If so, use this piece of jQuery:

```
$('#foo').val(0);
```

Comment: Could you give me the full script with what i gave above? It still seems to not function in IE